# Unit test React functional component's function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, react-functional-component

is there anyway we can unit test a function in a react Functional component. Since `wrapper.instance()` will return null for functional components what's the best way to include this function in test to get maximum coverage.

```
const SimpleFC: React.FC = () => {

    const callbackFunction = () => {
        // Do Stuffs
    }

    return (
        <ChildComponent callback={callbackFunction} />
    )
}

export { SimpleFC };
```

In this code segment how can we invoke the `callbackFunction` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: IMHO tests should not be focused on implementation details . Asserting whether a function is called doesn't add any value . Instead what you should do is test how the UI changes when that xyz function is called. Does something got added to the UI or removed from the UI . You test should be focused more on how the user will use your app . The user doesn't care about whether your callbackFunction is called . All he cares is what he sees in the UI .

Comment: What's the _behaviour_ that callback implements? How's ChildComponent going to trigger it?

Comment: @Shyam yes what the user care is an UI change, but for the UI to change we need to to trigger the function. My question is how to call the function without interacting the child component.

Answer (score 0):

Through you are using `wrapper.instance()` API, I arbitrarily think that you are using the `enzyme` library. You can use [.invoke(invokePropName)(...args) => Any](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/invoke.html) method to invoke a function prop on `ChildComponent` directly.

E.g.

`SimpleFC.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';

const SimpleFC: React.FC = () => {
  const callbackFunction = () => {
    // Do Stuffs
    console.log('Do Stuffs');
  };

  return <ChildComponent callback={callbackFunction} />;
};

export { SimpleFC };
```

`ChildComponent.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function ChildComponent({ callback }) {
  return <div onClick={callback}>child component</div>;
}
```

`SimpleFC.test.tsx`:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import { SimpleFC } from './SimpleFC';

describe('67774847', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    const wrapper = shallow(<SimpleFC />);
    wrapper.invoke('callback')();
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('Do Stuffs');
    logSpy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67774847/SimpleFC.test.tsx (8.752 s)
  67774847
    ✓ should pass (48 ms)

  console.log
    Do Stuffs

      at console.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866:25)

--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files           |      90 |      100 |   66.67 |      90 |                   
 ChildComponent.tsx |   66.67 |      100 |       0 |   66.67 | 4                 
 SimpleFC.tsx       |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.654 s
```

Comment: I tried the `invoke` like this `wrapper.invoke('getCustomerAddress')()`

I am getting an error "This expression is not callable.
  Type 'never' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'."

Comment: @sinthu225 It's TS type issue, you can typecast to `any`. From your question, I can't reproducible this issue. There is no `getCustomerAddress` function prop in your question.

Comment: I disabled the linting and cast as any.

TypeError: ShallowWrapper::invoke() requires the name of a prop whose value is a function

Comment: `const wrapper = shallow(<Foo />);
wrapper.find('button').invoke('onClick')().then(() => {
  // expect()
});` This will work if we have a button or anything