# Jest: Function Unit Test in React Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to test the function inside **React Functional Component** (not Class Component)

Here is my component:

```js
const Component: React.FC = () => {
  const [openMenu, setOpenMenu] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const toggleMenu = () => setOpenMenu((prev) => !prev);

  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent openMenu={openMenu} toggleMenu={toggleMenu} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

I tried to run simple test and it's failed

```js
  test('should be able to toggle open menu state', async () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
          <DefaultLayout />
        </MemoryRouter>
      </Provider>
    );

    // wrapper.invoke('toggleMenu')();
    expect(wrapper.state('openMenu')).toBe(false);
  });
```

What I want to test is `toggleMenu` function update the `openMenu` correctly. I saw some answer from stackoverflow able to test with `instance()` or `invoke()` but that only apply for class component. Is that anyway to test function and state inside component without fire any event?

- [Unit test React functional component's function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67774847/unit-test-react-functional-components-function)

Comment: That is how your component works though. A user fires an event in the browser and the menu opens. Your test should replicate how a user interacts with the component.

Comment: can't test specific function in the component?

Comment: You cannot test specific functions in the component. Either replicate user events that trigger the toggleMenu function or move toggleMenu outside the component.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write test case directly to the function without fire event. Because there is no `this` identifier like class component so, we can't use instance to get the events. If you use `fireEvent.press("test map response")` it will automatically get you state to coverage.